# sort nested object to be consecutive and ascending

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object. What I am doing is appending a new object to the main object then deleting one of the nested objects and it works fine. What I am trying to do is once I delete one of the nested objects I want to sort the rest by ascending order but also rename the keys to be consecutive. To explain that better say once I remove a nested object my main object is this `{ 0: {}, 1: {}, 3: {}}` meaning nested object key `2` has been removed, now what I want is to change the keys to be `{ 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}}` so that they are ascending and consecutive. Thanks in advance.

```js
var myObject = {
  0: {
    "category": "myCategory1",
    "title": "myTitle1"
  },
  1: {
    "category": "myCategory2",
    "title": "myTitle2"
  }
}

const currentObjectKeys = Object.keys(myObject).sort();

const nextObjectKey = parseInt(currentObjectKeys[currentObjectKeys.length - 1]) + 1

myObject = Object.assign({
  [nextObjectKey]: {
    "category": "myCategory3",
    "title": "myTitle3"
  }
}, myObject)

delete myObject['1'];

//right here sort myObject by key then print myObject but say if the keys are 0 & 2
//I want to change the keys to 0 & 1 and this should work with any length of nested objects

console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: "I want to sort the rest by ascending order". Object don't have order.

Comment: do you really need an object? why not an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a data structure whose integer keys start at 0 and do not have holes, you should use an array, not an object - then all you need to do is splice the value out of the array, and the rest will be re-arranged appropriately. Pushing a value becomes much easier too.

```js
const categories = [{
  "category": "myCategory1",
  "title": "myTitle1"
}, {
  "category": "myCategory2",
  "title": "myTitle2"
}];

// instead of nextObjectKey and Object.assign, just do:
categories.push({
  "category": "myCategory3",
  "title": "myTitle3"
});

// instead of delete and resort, do:
categories.splice(1, 1);
// (index to remove, number of values to remove)
console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would agree, not sure an object is the right tool here, not knowing the background. But to answer the question as posted:

```js
const originalObject = {
  0: {
    "category": "myCategory1",
    "title": "myTitle1"
  },
  3: {
    "category": "myCategory3",
    "title": "myTitle3"
  },
  7: {
    "category": "myCategory7",
    "title": "myTitle7"
  }
};

const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(originalObject)
    .sort(([k,v]) => k)
    .map(([k,v], i) => [i,v])
);

console.log(newObject);
```